# Cajole QUERY to accept text string for the data range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a query statement pulling data from multiple sheets, which works fine:

```
=QUERY({'A Physical Science'!A2:L; 'B Physical Science'!A2:L; 'E Physical Science'!A2:L; 'F Physical Science'!A2:L; 'G Physical Science'!A2:L},"select Col11 where Col6 is not null",0)
```

When I tried creating a dynamic source for the data range though, it no longer works. I successfully created a text string formula that matches the original data range exactly

```
{'A Physical Science'!A2:L; 'B Physical Science'!A2:L; 'E Physical Science'!A2:L; 'F Physical Science'!A2:L; 'G Physical Science'!A2:L}
```

but no matter how I call the data range in a neighboring QUERY statement, it just returns the text string. `INDEX, ARRAYFORMULA, INDIRECT`, curly brackets, nothing brings the data range text string to life.

@Ruben, I added my old function to your script to be dynamic, and have it triggered to run when the google sheet is opened. Just checking if there is a more elegant way of accomplishing this?

```
function RangeArray() {
const skiplast = 5; //last 5 sheets need not be arrayed
var data = ""; //initialize string that will be the data range
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length - skiplast ; i++) {
  data = data + "'"+ [ sheets[i].getName() ] + "'!A2:Z" ; //append the sheet names to the data string, plus necessary bits for parsing
  if (i<sheets.length - skiplast -1) {data = data + ";"} //except for the last sheet, also append a semicolon
  else {}
}

const here = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('DO NOT EDIT!A1');
const formula = '{'+ data +'}'; // make an array out of the data string
here.setFormula(formula);
}
```

Comment: Currently, the names of the tabs are fixed in my query. If I add extra tabs or delete or change their names, I then need to edit the query statement. By making the query data range dynamic, tab names would be automatically read from helper cells (found a script for that) and a new query statement created without any editing needed.

Comment: Regarding "INDEX, ARRAYFORMULA, INDIRECT, curly brackets, nothing brings the data range text string to life." please show how you tried to used this functions.

Comment: Given that the data range string is in A1, Then the next cell down, A2, was either =QUERY(A1,"select Col11 where Col6 is not null",0) or =QUERY({A1},"select Col11 where Col6 is not null",0) or =QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(A1),"select Col11 where Col6 is not null",0)  or =QUERY(INDIRECT(A1),"select Col11 where Col6 is not null",0) or =QUERY(INDEX(A1,1),"select Col11 where Col6 is not null",0) ; none of these worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no way to convert a cell value like

```
{'A Physical Science'!A2:L; 'B Physical Science'!A2:L; 'E Physical Science'!A2:L; 'F Physical Science'!A2:L; 'G Physical Science'!A2:L}
```

into an Google Sheets array using Google Sheets built-in functions but it is possible to use Google Apps Script, to use this value as the parameter of one of the `setFormula` methods, i.e.:

```js
function addArray(){
  const a1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('Sheet1!A1');
  const formula = `{'A Physical Science'!A2:L; 'B Physical Science'!A2:L; 'E Physical Science'!A2:L; 'F Physical Science'!A2:L; 'G Physical Science'!A2:L}`;
  a1.setFormula(formula);
}
```

Comment: well, shoot! That seems to be some pretty obvious functionality that should be there from the start. Thanks, I will add  this function to my library and see what happens!

Comment: Thank you, @Ruben! I edited my original question with my version your solution, can you let me know if its too ugly?

Comment: @user2517718 You are welcome. Follow up questions should be posted as new question, not as an edit of the original. Anyway, yes is too ugly :P I suggest you to learn about Array methods like like forEach and reduce and about the [+= operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)